# Opera browser is not playing audio

Tags: windows, audio, opera

My issue is that opera browser on windows has stopped playing audio , while chrome and other browsers and any other media player in my computer do.

I've tried to check site settings but opera has sound access and I've also tried to delete cache and then tried to update opera browser and then tried to reinstall it but non of these solutions worked.

Comment: Did you check the [Volume mixer](https://www.windowsdigitals.com/wp-content/uploads/Headset-volume-too-loud-Windows-11.jpg)

Comment: thanks a lot the problem was with the volume mixer @MarkusMeyer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the volume mixer and the value of the app:

[image]